# Not able to get a hyperlinked field in django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've two models in my `model.py`  Transaction and Split. A transaction can have many splits and I am trying to get django-rest-frameowrk to return response with hyper-linked relationship.

Something along the lines of this :

```
{
    "count": 1, 
    "next": null, 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        {
            "desc": "House Rent", 
            "currency": "INR", 
            "amount": 5000.0, 
            "splits": [
                       'http://www.example.com/api/splits/45/',
                       'http://www.example.com/api/splits/46/',
                       'http://www.example.com/api/splits/47/',
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But no matter which field i try for the splits field in my TransactionSerializer I always get a response link this :

```
{
    "count": 1, 
    "next": null, 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        {
            "desc": "House Rent", 
            "currency": "INR", 
            "amount": 5000.0, 
            "splits": [
                1, 
                2
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The models and serializers that I've written are below 
Models :

```
  class Transaction(models.Model):
        desc = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        currency = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        amount = models.FloatField()


  class Split(models.Model):
        transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, \
                                        related_name='splits' )
        userid = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        split = models.IntegerField()

        class Meta:
            unique_together = ('transaction', 'userid')
```

Serializers :

```
class SplitSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Split
            fields = ('transaction', 'userid', 'split')

class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    split = HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, \
                                    view_name='split-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ('desc', 'currency', 'amount', 'splits')
```

If you need the entire code of the project its available on github [here](https://github.com/aashudwivedi/money_django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename `split` to `splits` on your `TransactionSerializer`.

Right now, you have `split` defined as the `HyperlinkedRelatedField` you are looking for.  You are not including `split` in the `fields` tuple within the serializer metadata, so it is not being included in the output.  Once you rename it to `splits`, it will be included in the output correctly and use the right relationship to generate the links.

Without the rename, currently the serializer is [auto-generating](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/08772799d466907a16f02aec990396736be3c022/rest_framework/serializers.py#L816-L846) the `splits` field as a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`.  This is why you are getting integers as the output instead of the links you were expecting.

Comment: Worked Perfectly, Thanks a ton for the quick help :)